# Spring boot integration testing issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing

I am working on a project, i have completed but issue is in project i have to write integration testing code.

> This is the controller

```
 @PostMapping("/newgame")
    public ResponseEntity<Players> beginNewGame(@RequestBody Players players) {

        Players savedPersion = playerService.beginNewGame(players);

        return savedPersion!=null ?  ResponseEntity.ok(savedPersion):
                (ResponseEntity<Players>) ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

> And this is service.

```
@Override
    public Players beginNewGame(Players players) {

            //new game state
            GameState gameState =new GameState();
            gameState.setWinner("null");


        GameState save = gameStateRepositery.save(gameState);

        //new score
        Score score = new Score();
        score.setGameId(save.getId());

        Score savedScore = scoreRepositery.save(score);
        players.setScoreId(savedScore.getId());
        players.setGameId(save.getId());

        Players savedPlayers=null;
            savedPlayers= playersRepositery.save(players);

        System.out.println(savedScore.getGameId()+"ksdjfkjskn");

       return savedPlayers;
    }
```

> And if i hit the endpoints with proper required parameters, the is
> working fine, and return me.

```
{
    "gameId": 57,
    "id": 1,
    "playerOne": "vinitSaini",
    "playerTwo": "anonymousKal",
    "scoreId": 58
}
```

> This is the testing code, how i can check  what the response is
> returning.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class PlayersIntTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private PlayersRepositery playersRepositery;


    @Test
    void newGame() throws Exception {
        
        //mockMvc.perform(post("/api/{forumId}/register", 42L)
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/newgame")
                .contentType("application/json")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(players)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());




    }
```

**So please help me to write integration testing.**

Comment: have you tried anything ? can you show the test class ?

Comment: Please check now i have addaed my testing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the response in JSON and check values of JSON properties using [MockMvcResultMatchers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html)

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/api/newgame")
       .contentType("application/json")
       .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(players)))
       .andExpect(status().isOk())
       .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content()
          .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
       .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.gameId")
          .value(57))
       .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id")
          .value(1))
       .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.playerOne")
          .value("vinitSaini"))
       .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.playerTwo")
          .value("anonymousKal"))
       .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.scoreId")
          .value(58));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Test
void newGame() throws Exception {

```
    //mockMvc.perform(post("/api/{forumId}/register", 42L)
    ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/newgame")
            .contentType("application/json")
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(players)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    String responseInJson = resultActions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    Players responseObj = objectMapper.readValue(responseInJson, Players.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull(responseObj);
    // You can add all asserts here


}
```